# Visual Studio : Is there a way to Perform a "Find in files" with one single shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to select an expression in code and type Ctrl+Whatever
so it has the same result as [ Ctrl+Shift+F AND Clicking on "Find All" ]

EDIT : [Ctrl+Shift+F AND Hitting Enter] may be quicker than clicking but I still want something more specific and faster

**Remark :** I am NOT interested the  *Find All References* shortcut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a macro.  I recorded and modified one in VS2010:

```
Sub FindAllFiles()
    DTE.Find.FindWhat = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.ToString()
    DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetFiles
    DTE.Find.MatchCase = False
    DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = False
    DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = True
    DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral
    DTE.Find.SearchPath = "Entire Solution"
    DTE.Find.SearchSubfolders = True
    DTE.Find.FilesOfType = ""
    DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResults1
    DTE.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionFindAll
    If (DTE.Find.Execute() = vsFindResult.vsFindResultNotFound) Then
        Throw New System.Exception("vsFindResultNotFound")
    End If
End Sub
```

The macro can be set to a keyboard shortcut.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Did not know about this, hough I knew something like that had to be available. That will open the path to a series of Macros I will write to make my dull code-typing life easier. ThanX.

Comment: Besides, This solution is perfect because it makes it possible to have different Shortcuts/Macros for specific find scopes (SOlution/Project/Etc...). ThanX 4 Sharing

Answer (score 4):

Not that I would be aware of it. `Ctrl+Shift+F + ENTER` (**ENTER** instead of *Clicking on "Find All"*) is probably the closest it comes. And if you are a touch typist it is as fast as a single shortcut.

**Update**

Now, that the question has changed my answer makes no sense anymore. Go with a macro like [Fosco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980885/visual-studio-is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-find-in-files-with-one-single-short/4981042#4981042) answered it.

Comment: I would suspect that because the OP wants a *single* shortcut rather than having to hit 3 keys and then enter.

Comment: @ChrisF: Well, I can't help it if it doesn't exists. If you are a touch typist this is as quick as a single shortcut ;)

Comment: @bratao: No, he did not! The OP wrote `Clicking on "Find All"` and you don't have to do that, you can just press the ENTER key.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes, My Bad. I did not Specify that you're right. I do know that indeed. Of course it is far better that clicking. But I still look for soemting more efficient. Edited the question to be more precise

Comment: Well, now that you have changed your question my answer makes of course no sense anymore. `Ctrl+Shift+F + ENTER` works fast enough for me, if you wan't a single shortcut, go with a macro.

Comment: There you Go : I've put a +1 to you, don't be sad :-) and edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: @Mika Jacobi: I'm not sad at all ;) I'm just trying to avoid future downvotes by making clear that the question has changed since I gave the answer. It's generally good style to make edits in questions transparent (as you did now) that future readers have an understanding why some answers were given as they are.

Comment: @Martin : You have been downvoted abusively by someone DEFORE my edit. SO that was not very fair from the downvoter. Anyway, case clear now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar macro in use like @Fosco.

```
' Members for the search methods
Private matchCase As Boolean = True
Private searchWindowOne As Boolean = False

Public Sub SearchFiles(ByVal fileTypes As String, ByVal searchPath As String)
    searchWindowOne = Not searchWindowOne
    DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetFiles
    DTE.Find.MatchCase = matchCase
    DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = matchWholeWord
    matchCase = True
    matchWholeWord = True
    DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = True
    DTE.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionFindAll
    DTE.Find.SearchPath = searchPath
    If (searchWindowOne) Then
        DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResults1
    Else
        DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResults2
    End If
    DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral
    DTE.Find.SearchSubfolders = True
    DTE.Find.FilesOfType = fileTypes
    DTE.Find.FindWhat = GetClipboard()
    If (DTE.Find.Execute() = vsFindResult.vsFindResultNotFound) Then
        Throw New System.Exception("vsFindResultNotFound")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ChangeMatchCase()
    matchCase = False
    matchWholeWord = False
End Sub
```

It adds a little more flexibility to the original approach.
One of the good things is that is searches into both find windows **alternating**.
That means your last two searches are always accessible.
Of course this can't be used to be directly mapped to a shortcut but it allows to do this:

```
Sub SearchInProject()
    SearchFiles("*.*", "Current Project")
End Sub
Sub SearchInCode()
    SearchFiles("*.h;*.cpp", "Entire Solution")
End Sub
```

...and so on. These can then be mapped to shortcuts and allow real one key searching.
As you might have noticed I added a switch for match case that can be activated by the macro `ChangeMatchCase` for the next search.
In my setting I mapped different searches to double keystrokes.
So `Ctrl+F,Ctrl+G` searches globally, `Ctrl+F,Ctrl+D`searches in the project, ... you get the point. I have similar mappings for all debug stuff starting with `Ctrl+D,`.
This was maybe the single most important performance boost I had in the last years.